# Insert custom Task into build-in task's dependency in SBT

Tags: android, scala, sbt, proguard, android-sdk-plugin

Here is my scenario, I'm using Scala / SBT / android-sdk-plugin to develop Android application. In my application, I'm planning to use [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

It has published to maven repository, so I could easily reference it in my project by using SBT's config file.

But the problem is that it includes it's dependency `android-support-v4.jar` in in own source tree, which will be unpacked to `target/apklibs/com.viewpagerindicator-library-2.4.1/libs/android-support-v4.jar` during compiling the project.

This will cause `android:proguard` to crash, since android-support-v4.jar is already imported by the SBT itself from dependency.

What I have done is writing an SBT task to delete that file, so my `build.sbt` now looks like the following:

```
import android.Keys._

import android.Dependencies.{apklib,aar}

android.Plugin.androidBuild

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

organization := "idv.brianhsu.maidroid.ui"

libraryDependencies += "com.viewpagerindicator" % "library" % "2.4.1"

platformTarget in Android := "android-19"

proguardScala in Android := true

lazy val cleanupDuplicateJar = taskKey[Unit]("Remove duplicate jar")

cleanupDuplicateJar := {
  import java.io.File
  println("Remove target/apklibs/com.viewpagerindicator-library-2.4.1/libs/android-support-v4.jar")
  val file = new File("target/apklibs/com.viewpagerindicator-library-2.4.1/libs/android-support-v4.jar")
  file.delete()
}
```

It works quite fine, but I have to run `cleanupDuplicateJar` manually before `android:proguard` every time.

How could I make `cleanupDuplicateJar` automatically run when I run `android:proguard`? More specifically, at the time point that is after all built-in dependency task of `android:proguard`, like `compile`, and before `android:progurad` it self.

Or how could I declare which jar to ignore just by using android-sdk-plugins's built-in settings?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found I could excludes JAR files by setting the following config at `build.sbt`.

```
proguardLibraries in Android += new java.io.File("target/apklibs/com.viewpagerindicator-library-2.4.1/libs/android-support-v4.jar")
```